# Detect "right" from body and add 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a pen to move the body through the viewport and simulate pages outside of the window.

I have written a script that will detect the "right" css declaration and add or subtract 100% to simulate the viewport moving around the content. I would like to do this with the top using 
`var = vertical`.

I'm not very good at Javascript, so please let me know if there are easier ways to work through my variables. After realizing that `.css` pulls a string, I had to use `parseInt`.

```
$('.right.arrow-link').click(function () {
    var vertical = parseInt($('body').css('top'), 10);
    var horizontal = parseInt($('body').css('right'), 10);
    var newhorizontal = horizontal + 100;
    var newhorizontal = newhorizontal.toString() + '%';
    $('body').css('right', newhorizontal);
});
$('.left.arrow-link').click(function () {
    var horizontal = parseInt($('body').css('right'), 10);
    alert(horizontal);
    var newhorizontal = horizontal - 100;
    var newhorizontal = newhorizontal.toString() + '%';
    $('body').css('right', newhorizontal);
});
```

Edit it [Here](http://codepen.io/tpalmer75/pen/lsnJg):

Comment: To be clear: the issue is when I click your right arrow, it loads the page, but when I click the left arrow, it doesn't return to the default screen (looks like that's the issue when I just tried it). Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, the left arrow should return to the main screen. Essentially, the left arrow should read the current "right" position of the body and subtract 100%. Thus, if the left arrow is clicked on the default screen, it would set to body to `right: -100%;`

Edit: the new `right` declaration appears to be affected by the size of the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS transitions, and just track horizontal and vertical numbers per click. You need the CSS transition on the .wrapper to make it all animate nicely.

```
 .wrapper {
     transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 }
```

However, you're redeclaring your vertical and horizontal variables on every click, which resets them, and will make it impossible to add more boxes and grids to the left and right of subsequent pages. This is causing stuff to fly around. [EDIT: added up and down as well] Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var vertical = 0;
  var horizontal = 0;

  $('.right.arrow-link').click(function(){

        horizontal -= 100;
        $('body').css('left', horizontal + '%');

   });

    $('.left.arrow-link').click(function(){

        horizontal += 100;
        $('body').css('left', horizontal + '%');
   });
   $('.up.arrow-link').click(function() {
        vertical -=100;
        $('body').css('top', vertical + '%');
   });
   $('.down.arrow-link').click(function() {
        vertical +=100;
        $('body').css('top', vertical + '%');
   });
});
```

The .wrapper style with the transitions assumes that all of your extra pages will use that class. This will set up the CSS transition animation for all of them in one fell swoop.

Also, please note that in your CSS you've only specified -webkit-transform in a couple places, which makes this break in FireFox. You can fix that by just adding the transform version as well.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nsJDr

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for the tips. I was only intending on using this myself which is why I had not written the transition prefixes. Your solution is what I originally had in mind, however declaring this for every single page would be tiresome. (What if I went 15 pages to the right?) This is why I am looking to find why the left arrow is setting the body so far over.

Comment: Ah, got it! Please add that consideration to your question, as that definitely does change how I'd answer this. I'll have another look at your code and update.

Comment: Updated. This continues to assume that each page is 100% width. You could easily update this with a variable for the page width, or track that on browser resize.

Comment: Smart, I was overthinking. This works nicely. The first transition doesn't work, but I'm looking into this.

Comment: The transition didn't work for the first click because the body had no "left" declaration. Thanks! Now to figure out how to get the top and bottom clicks to work...

Comment: For anyone wondering: Body must be absolutely positioned for top or bottom declarations to work.

Comment: I would think that for top and bottom, you'd just use the exact same logic, using the vertical variable, and a top declaration, right? I'll update my answer. Please upvote if it works for you!

Comment: The same logic does work, and I have it all working in my new update: http://codepen.io/tpalmer75/full/lsnJg . Sorry, I don't have the rep to upvote or I would!

Answer (score 0):

On you left arrow click, you don't want it to move 100% of the width of the screen, you just want it to move back to the start of the page. If there is going to be multiple sections, you will have to adjust this to move the width of the section your moving from though:

```
$('.left.arrow-link').click(function() {
    var horizontal = parseInt($('body').css('right'), 10);
    var newhorizontal = 0;

    newhorizontal = newhorizontal.toString() + '%';

    $('body').css('right', newhorizontal);
});
```

Here is a solution that keeps track of the wrapper and moves it the width of the current wrapper:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentWrapper = 1;

    $('.right.arrow-link').click(function() {

        var vertical = parseInt($('body').css('top'), 10);
        var horizontal = parseInt($('body').css('right'), 10);
        var newhorizontal = horizontal + 100;

        newhorizontal = newhorizontal.toString() + '%';

        $('body').css('right', newhorizontal);

        currentWrapper++;
    });

    $('.left.arrow-link').click(function() {
        var horizontal = parseInt($('body').css('right'), 10);
        var newhorizontal = horizontal - $(".wrapper.page-" + currentWrapper).width;

        newhorizontal = newhorizontal.toString() + '%';

        $('body').css('right', newhorizontal);

        if(currentWrapper > 1)
            currentWrapper--
    });
});
```

Comment: This would not work if I clicked the left arrow on the default page if I had a page on the left.

Comment: No, that's why I said you would have to get the width of each section if you are trying to move multiple times across the screen.

Comment: I added another version that uses the width of the current wrapper

Comment: The widths will always be 100%, which is why I had thought to simply add or subtract 100%. Shouldn't this be simple enough math for Javascript?

Comment: That is giving you the width of the entire screen isn't it? You want it to only move the width of the current .wrapper.page-# that is being displayed.